# Issue when reading env variable from .env file in docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

After upgrading the docker desktop to the `4.6.1` version. I'm started my project with `docker compose up` command in my project directory, But I got an error that the variable not set as the environment in my container.

This is my project tree:

```
- project
    - .env
    - docker-compose.yml
```

.env

```
SENSITIVE_KEY=ABC123#ABC123
```

docker-compose.yml `version: '3'`

```
...
    environment:
      - SENSITIVE_KEY=$SENSITIVE_KEY
...
```

I'm running `docker compose config` to check variable set truly in my docker-compose config, But i see this:

```
...
    environment:
      - SENSITIVE_KEY=ABC123
...
```

Everything after `#` was ignored in my variable!

Comment: `#` is for comments in yaml files. Maybe try `SENSITIVE_KEY='$SENSITIVE_KEY'`

Comment: In this case, my value is like this: `'''value'''`

Comment: you could try quoting it in the env file. Although this is sometimes problematic. Some programs are counting the quotes as part of the value. Otherwise, if you want to use quotes in the compose file, you need to quote the whole string `- "SENSITIVE_KEY=$SENSITIVE_KEY"` or use object syntax.

Comment: @TheFool just one out of many articles on the subject [DO **NOT** QUOTE VARIABLES IN YOUR DOCKER COMPOSE .ENV FILE](https://dev.to/tvanantwerp/don-t-quote-environment-variables-in-docker-268h)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. I am using the same steps from your question. Maybe you left some detail out.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `${SENSITIVE_KEY}`, if you would like to reference environment variables.

You can read more here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: That's missing the point of the problem. Its ok to do `$SOMEVAR`, its more or less the same as `${SOMEVAR}`, especially if you don't utilize the curly brackets further, like doing posix expansion tricks.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I have just updated my Docker, and I now see the same problem. I think its a bug in the newest compose, built-in in Docker CLI. It works with the previous version of `docker-compose` (v1.29.2)

Comment: OP is using the built in version of compose. At least as per question. `docker-compose` is a different python program.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didnt read your comment properly. I tried it too. I couldnt reproduce. What is your CLI version? I have `Docker Compose version v2.2.3`

Comment: Yes, true. I have lot of problems with the new one, so I still use the old one. My version of built-in compose is: `v2.3.3`